# Looking for a free scriptable load-testing tool

Tags: performance, stress-testing, load-testing

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to test a Rails-based JSON web service. LoadRunner would fit my needs, but I need a free solution.

Answer (score 3):

[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is free and scriptable, you should have a look.

Comment: seems it will test a web application..but basically i need to test Rails based JSON service and it will not be hosted on apache.

Comment: @user1518659 - JMeter can test any web-based system (including Rails and JSON). "Apache" is just a software foundation and includes many different projects, there is no relation between the Apache HTTP Web-server and Apache JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

What is your virtual user need?   Some of the commercial tools offer no cost versions at a limited load level, so before addressing your need I am looking for more specifics on the virtual user number requirements.

For clarification, are you looking for a tool which can produce a ACM/IEEE definition stress test from a scheduler perspective?   This would be a test which increases in load by a defined interval every ~n~ seconds|minutes|hours until the system collapses or a particular metric is achieved, such as response time exceeds SLA value by 250% for five minutes or CPU is greater than 90% for 45 seconds, etc....   Schedulers are all over the map in the tools space, some are better than others when it comes to Stress, most work equally well for a defined load level.

How does monitoring fit into your tool model?   Are there specific architectural components which you would like to monitor which would drive a tool?    This will help you identify system bottlenecks in the use of resources on architectural components.

What about your team skills?   You mention scripting, but how much are you expecting the tool to handle for you.  Some of the open source tools are great, but they mandate that a person be a highly skilled developer to get the most out of the tool.   The commercial side rounds some of the edges off of the tools, but in general you are still going to need to be proficient in the language of the tool.    If you need Python, that takes you one path, Java another, VB a third, Pascal a fourth, C a fifth, etc....   Sometimes its easier to document what languages you know and know well and concentrate on tools that fit that model as trying to learn a new tool and a new language at the same time rarely yields benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [AgileLoad](http://www.agileload.com) it is free for small test and provide both recording and advanced scipting features. It is compatible with JSon service. It is quite easy to use, there is also tutorials and video on how to use the tool on the website. Support is free and the support team can helps you with scripting process.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also take a look at [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/).  It has a nice feature where you can create your load script by recording your browser activity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of Load Tester that is free and has no limits on the number of virtual users you can run: [Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html).